# Skip an OTA update straight to next version, on Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, stock-android, android-versions

My not rooted Galaxy S4 Android 4.3 has received notification of an OTA update. By the size I know it's for Android 4.4.2 KitKat.

I know the phone provider has already released an OTA update for 5.0 Lollipop.

Can I skip the Kit Kat update and go straight to Lollipop? Or do previous updates need to be installed first?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to update via OTA, then yes. You have to upgrade in order. You could however, download the factory image for your device that has the LP  update and flash it via odin. But you might loose all your data and etc, depends on the image. So if you back it all up you could do it that way. But to be honest, the easiest way is to just download each update via OTA.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used Odin on my previous device, but it was rooted. I understand I need to root before using Odin. One advantage though was that I picked the ZTO version (no operator, no bloatware).  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You dont need root to use odin. Just need to put the device into download mode and off you go. You dont even need USB debugging enabled.